# Multiline regex for a Ruby on Rails log file

Tags: sed

I work with a Ruby on Rails log file which looks like the following example:

```
[...]
Started GET "/staff/sign_in" for 22.22.22.22 at 2014-02-16 03:39:32 -0800
Processing by Staffer::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered layouts/_compatible_browsers.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/headers/_guest.html.erb (0.6ms)
Cache digest for layouts/social_media_footer_link.html: bc9b2db49cc435f550be0f0dffe79548
Cache digest for layouts/_footer.html: 87dcaa136f1edad80dd5eb5a4b5dde82
Read fragment views/staffer_footer/87dcaa136f1edad80dd5eb5a4b5dde82/87dcaa136f1edad80dd5eb5a4b5dde82 (4.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (7.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 527ms (Views: 445.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
Started GET "/staff/sign_in" for 22.22.22.22 at 2014-02-16 03:49:32 -0800
Started GET "/staff/sign_in" for 22.22.22.22 at 2014-02-16 03:59:32 -0800
Processing by Staffer::SessionsController#new as */*
  Rendered layouts/_compatible_browsers.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/headers/_guest.html.erb (0.6ms)
Cache digest for layouts/social_media_footer_link.html: bc9b2db49cc435f550be0f0dffe79548
Read fragment views/staffer_footer/87dcaa136f1edad80dd5eb5a4b5dde82/87dcaa136f1edad80dd5eb5a4b5dde82 (4.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (7.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 527ms (Views: 445.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
[...]
```

How can I tell `sed` to give me the following output for that given example?

```
Started GET "/staff/sign_in" for 22.22.22.22 at 2014-02-16 03:39:32 -0800; Completed 200 OK in 527ms (Views: 445.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
Started GET "/staff/sign_in" for 22.22.22.22 at 2014-02-16 03:59:32 -0800; Completed 200 OK in 527ms (Views: 445.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.0ms)
```

Comment: This is more a case for `grep`, I guess. `grep "^Started\|^Completed" file` and then remove the new line.

Comment: I have some wired scenarios where I get two lines of `Started GET` in a row by using `grep`. I guess it is more a job for `sed`. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: `sed` is for `stream editor for filtering and transforming text`, while `grep` is `print lines matching a pattern`. Given your sample input, to me it makes more sense with `grep`, but please update with more representative input so that we can all together guess what's best.

Comment: I improved the example. Now there are 3 GETs but the result should only contain 2 GETs.

Comment: Is there any way of knowing which Started goes with which Completed?

Comment: That is the problem. I search for a way to make a best guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/Started GET/{h;d};/Completed 200 OK/{H;g;s/\n/; /p}' file
```

Better syntax:

```
sed -n '/Started GET/{h;d;};/Completed 200 OK/{H;g;s/\n/; /p;}' file
```

Comment: +1; All it takes to make this work on OSX too is to terminate the last command in each `{...}` block with `;` too: `sed -n '/Started GET/{h;d;};/Completed 200 OK/{H;g;s/\n/; /p;}' file`